# Return the values of form using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have an HTML form with drop down boxes, check boxes and text fields.

I am looking for a solution that returns the values of the form using javascript.

In other words, javascript must read the form and return the field names and values entered.

Return string should be something similar to the below:

ans00441, 908, txt00441, "I do not know yet", ans00442, "country 2", ans00442, "country 3", ans00442, "country 4", ans00444, "Very Much", txt00444, "Too much"

FORM1 below has been submitted as example.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

FORM1

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


function showResult(frm){
    alert('Display field names and values');
}   

 </SCRIPT>


            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <h2 id="qst00441">For who will you vote</h2>
                     <br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00441" value="908 ">Party 1<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00441" value="909 ">Party 2<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00441" value="910 ">Party 3<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00441" value="911 ">Party 4<br>
                     <br>Other Party<input type="text"  name="txt00441"  size="45" value="" ><br>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <h2 id="qst00442">Where do you live</h2>
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="ans00442" value="912 ">Country 1<br>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="ans00442" value="913 ">Country 2<br>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="ans00442" value="914 ">Country 3<br>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="ans00442" value="915 ">Country 4<br>
                     <br>Other country <input type="text"  name="txt00442"  size="45" value="" ><br>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <h2 id="qst00444">How much do you earn</h2>
                     <br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00444" value="921 ">Not to much<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00444" value="922 ">ok<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="ans00444" value="923 ">Very Much<br>
                     <br>Income <input type="text"  name="txt00444"  size="45" value="" ><br>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="Submit" name="btnSubmit1" onClick="showResult(this.form);"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend you to use `onSubmit` event in form except of `onClick` in button, because you could get problems: users can press enter in `input-text` and function won't be processed.

This is code (but you will need jQuery), which goes through every input in `#form` and does some security.

```
function showResult() {
    var result = '';
    $('#form input').each(function() {
        var self = $(this),
            type = self.attr('type'),
            name = self.attr('name'),
            value = self.val(),
            checked = self.is(':checked');

        if( value.length > 0 && type == 'text' || ( (type == 'radio' || type == 'checkbox') && checked) ) {
            result += name + ', ';
            result += value + ', ';
        }
    });
    $('#form').html(result);
}
```

Here is fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/JG7A9/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get json from the form:

```
 var frm = $(document.myform);
 var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` and last format the string in the bucle, for a pure javascript solution.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    elementsLength = elements.length,
    result = '';

for( var i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++ ){
    var element = elements[i];

    result += element.name + ',' + element.value+ ',';
}
```

[You can see this running here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEOLPAR/hY7EZ/)

[You could see more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)